# BlackBerry Webworks Signing Failed

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-webworks

I am attempting to package and sign a BlackBerry webworks application from within the Ripple emulator (I've also tried this with bbwp).

Packaging works fine, but signing returns the really helpful error message `[ERROR] Signing failed`.

I have installed the three csi files using SignatureTool (java -jar SignatureTool.jar client-Rxx-xxx.csi).

I've tried running bbwp in verbose mode, and it was as unhelpful.

```
...
No errors.
[INFO]              Starting signing tool
[ERROR]             Signing failed
```

Have I missed out a step?

What are the possible causes for this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to get package & sign working on the command line using bbwp. I'm not sure why it's working this way, and also why it's still not working in Ripple.

Resolution:

- [Requested new signing keys from Blackberry](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/signingkey) (I imagine this step wasn't necessary)
- Installed each of the three keys using SignatureTool.jar found in the BlackBerry Webworks SDK/bin directory: `java -jar SignatureTool.jar ~/BB/client-RBB-xxx.csi`
- Package using Ripple
- Signed as follows: `./bbwp ~/BB/Testy.zip -g -v -o ~/BB/output` with Testy.zip being the package produced by Ripple.
- Results in a packaged and signed app which can be tested on a device. Happy.